# sympy: Vector/Matrix repetition

Tags: python, matrix, sympy

What is the most elegant way in `sympy` to construct a matrix from a repeated
vector. That is, given a row vector

```
     V = [ v00, v01, v02 ]
```

the goal is to find an operation `op` such that

```
     M = op(V, N)
```

delivers a matrix `M` consisting of `N` rows which are equal to `V`, i.e.

```
    /  v00  v01  v02  \
    |  v00  v01  v02  |
M = |      ...        |
    |                 | 
    \  v00  v01  v02  /
```

similar to what can be achieved by `tile` in `numpy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot gurantee that this is the most elegant way to do it and probably you are already using something like this but the following works:

```
import sympy as s

def copyRow(N,V):
    M = V
    for i in range(N):
        M = M.row_insert(1,V)
    return M

v00,v01,v02 = s.symbols('v00,v01,v02')

V = s.Matrix([ [v00, v01, v02 ] ])

M = copyRow(5,V)
```